# Couchbase N1QL query error on keyword nested path

Tags: sql, couchbase, sql++

`SELECT data FROM users WHERE data.role = "ADMIN"`

This query returns an error because of the reserved keyword `role` from SQL. Same for `password`.
I have created the index:

`CREATE INDEX loginSearchIndex ON users(`data.role`) USING GSI`
(using a ` char is the only way this works. If I do the same in the query, it will not return any results.

For nested objects that don't have any reserved keywords, it works just fine.
Any ideas of how I can escape the reserved keyword when running an N1QL query?

All the query tests are performed in the Query Workbenck

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/reservedwords.html

Comment: Actually, that exact command doesn't work but your comment led me to a different page. Writing the answer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, after digging around a bit I found how it should be done

Create the index and you can use as many nested fields as you like but using the ` char:

```
CREATE INDEX loginSearchIndex ON users(data.`role`) USING GSI
```

Then you run the Query

```
SELECT data FROM users WHERE data.`role` = "ADMIN"
```

Works fine

**UPDATE**:
If you have nested JSON, you can wrap each key in `. Don't forget to add the necessary index

```
SELECT data FROM users WHERE data.`children`.`rockets`.`elon`.`age` = "48"
```

Comment: Note: It is only required to put field names inside back-ticks when they are reserved words (such as "role") or contain special characters (including space, dash, etc.).